# Is there a size limit for HTML5 Manifest?

Tags: html, size, limit, manifest

I have been looking into HTML5 manifest but I am unclear as to whether or not there is file size limit for caching using the manifest.

For example if i wanted to make several audio files available offline would this be achieved using manifest? or is it really only for small images and text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as far as i know [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html) doesn't specify a maximum size for an object or for the entire cache, but e.g. firefox has a preference which by default allows a total of 50mb worth of cache-files. that implies that indeed the cache is optimized for small files (html, css, js, images) and not for big files (video, audio, ...).