# What are the HTML5 Cache (Manifest) storage limits (set by each browser)?

Tags: html

I'm trying to find a way to store large amounts of data (100-500 MB, ideally) on the iPad browser, Chrome, and FireFox (latest versions).

I see that there are several options. App Cached Manifest seems like the best option, but I can't see what the limits are.

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757945/cache-manifest-size-limit-and-web-apps

Comment: The [spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html) doesn't set a hard limit but browsers do. And it's different for each one. I think modern browsers will ask the user for permission to increase the cache size if an app needs more after 5 or 10mb.