# Local storage and cached resources

Tags: html, local-storage, html5-appcache, html5-apps

I'm a bit confused around the 5MB limit that Local Storage provides. Does this include the caching of images and files determined in a manifest file in a HTML5 APP for example?

Comment: Browsers don't have the concept of a "manifest file" for web apps, so I think you have to explain more abut the context. The 5 MB restriction applies to data that is stored via the [`localStorage` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage), not to all local data.

Comment: Actually, HTML5 browsers do have a manifest system for offline apps. See [this link](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html)

Comment: OK, I think this is becoming clearer.  localStorage specifies what is stored locally. The caching of such objects like images etc is separate to local storage

Comment: @MikeW: Wow, I didn't know that. Doesn't seem to have anything to do with `lovalStorage` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit for `LocalStorage` is different from the limit used for Application Cache. Each browser has a different size, and people have found these values by experimenting with examples. You can have a look at these limits on http://grinninggecko.com/developing-cross-platform-html5-offline-app-1/.

There exists a related StackOverflow question about the limit for Application Cache on [Cache Manifest Size Limit and Web Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757945/cache-manifest-size-limit-and-web-apps).